# How to expose helm to kubernetes deployment which is with golang application

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am writing a Golang application which is more like automating the helm install, so I would like to know how to expose helm to your Kubernetes deployment or any API that creates helm object which can communicate with the tiller directly for the instruction, please describe the answer with a piece of code. thanks

I have been trying with the package https://godoc.org/k8s.io/helm/pkg/helm but does not really know what are the parameters that we need to pass when creating helm client

Answer (score 0):

Not to discourage you, but I thought I should point out that Helm is nearing a v3 release, which will entirely remove tiller, and hence the client will likely change also.

Here are some relevant links:

- [Helm v3.0.0-beta.3 release notes](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta.3)
- [Helm v3 Beta 1 Released blog post](https://helm.sh/blog/helm-v3-beta/)

Hope this helps.